# Multiple war files which load natives

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

We have started using our new in-house built authorization library from this version. It internally loads a native file `.so` and then does whatever it has to (Before it used to do based on regex).

Now in our application, we have 2 different war files that are deployed on the same tomcat in production. Both of them use this authorization library and hence both of those class loaders try loading the native file twice. Which of-course the jvm does not allow as you can only load it once.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib64/xxxx-0.1.0.so already loaded in another classloader
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1903)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
   ....
```

One solution to this problem is that, we put this authorization jar in the tomcat/lib. So that because the tomcat common class loader loads it, they are automatically available to child class-loaders (so the war files) and everyone can access it. But this solution needs special maintenance. And I dont like this tweaking. I might as well do some config if possible in my maven pom.

Is there any other simpler solution to this kind of problem? Its a pure spring application, maven based.

Comment: It looks like snappy-java [did it](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/issues/24), main ingredient: "have a static block that determines the appropriate native library to load, copies it to a unique location in the file system, then calls System.loadLibrary with that absolute path".
Implementation is [here](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/xerial/snappy/SnappyLoader.java) (uses `System.load(nativeLibFile.getAbsolutePath());`). I will be interested to see if/how this works in your case.